# How to click on each payment method in cypress using iteration?

Tags: javascript, cypress, browser-automation

My requirement is to click on each and every payment method (pay-safe, visa, bit-pay etc.)
and then validate using assert method by comparing URL.

Problem : Unable to click on element. I'm getting null value in variable. Tried using val() as well as html() method.

I tried below code.

```
//cy.get('.real-money--providers-list') = allPaymentMethods

  depositFiat.allPaymentMethods().find('[src*="providers/logo"]').each(($element, index, $list) => {
    var namePaymentProvider = $element.find('[alt*="safe"]').text()
    cy.log(namePaymentProvider)
    cy.wait(1000)

      if(namePaymentProvider.includes('class')){
        $element.find('.provider-content--choice').click()
        //cy.get('.provider-content').invoke('removeAttr','src').click()
        //depositFiat.secureCheckout().click()
        //cy.back()
      }
})
```

As cypress unable to handle child windows I tried to use invoke method but no luck.

Find [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/24m1agwu/1/) here
[image: Log file shows null value]

Comment: Looks like the problem is with this line 

    `var namePaymentProvider = $element.find('[alt*="safe"]').text()`

it evaluates to nothing.

Does this element exist? What happens in you search for `[alt*="safe"]` in the DOM? Does it find any elements? Does it have a text? Or is it a value?

Comment: Here is HTML view.  https://ibb.co/bPDK7Gp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="provider-img"><img alt="safecharge_paysafecard" class="style__Logo-a3ugi5-2 fAwRoV visible" src="https://static.xyz.com/1234123463/img/providers/logo_safecharge_paysafecard.svg"></div>
```

As per your HTML fiddle, I could see that for every payment provider you can use the css selector `img[class*="style__Logo"]`

For one payment method you can use:

```
cy.get('img[class*="style__Logo"]').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'src').should('contain', 'https: //static.xyz.com/')
```

Comment: `cy.get('.provider-img').each(($ele) => {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
    //do something
})`

Able to click on element but how to manipulate DOM using `invoke('removeAttr','src')` so that I can click on each provider then assert using URL. `cy.go('back')` also Tried to implement this. Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to assert? Please paste the value from the HTML code.

Comment: Here is HTML view. ibb.co/bPDK7Gp
Need to assert that when user click on any payment method and then after clicking on SECURE CHECKOUT it opens in new window and anything can be compare (URL contains https://).

Comment: So you have to go click on the payment method and then click on the checkout button, check the URL and then again click on the payment method 2 and repeat the process ?

Comment: [HTML] (https://jsfiddle.net/24m1agwu/1/)
Just need to check each and every payment method is working. (simply URL contains https::// is enough)

Comment: So when you click the payment method you just need to check the URL?

Comment: Yes. That is needed for now.

Comment: Need to validate each and every payment method is working. Simple idea is to ASSERT URL value. `https://`

Comment: So can you are give me an example of the URL like when you select bitpay, how the URL looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232238/discussion-between-qa-selenium-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 1):

You are finding an image, then trying to click on it.
Most likely the click-event sits on the button

Instead try to click on the button:

```
cy.get('.provider-content').each($element => {
  cy.wrap($element).click()
  // Assert something here
})
```

If the click action opens up a new tab/window, and you want to assert that it moved you do this new link, then Cypress does not support this directly.
Instead, you would either get the url that *should* be opened by the click and verify that.

Or

Stub the browser window so that the new tab opens up in the same tab you are currently in.

Comment: you would either get the url that should be opened by the click and verify that.

This can also work. I tried to use `cy.get('.provider-img').invoke('removeAttr','src').click({ multiple: true })` this but your approach makes scene.

Comment: `var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      cy.get('img[class*="style__Logo"]').eq(i).invoke('attr', 'src').should('contain', 'https://static.XYZ.com')
    }`
I tried this approach.
Credits @Alapan Das

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion) and [Jquery `.removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) :

```
    cy.get('[src*="providers/logo"]') //You need to make sure here is the correct selector that covers all methods here
        .then(methods => {
            checkPaymentMethod
            function checkPaymentMethod(methodNumber = 0) {
                if(methodNumber < methods.length) {
                    Cypress.$(methods[methodNumber]).removeAttr("target");
                    cy.get(methods[methodNumber])
                        .click()
                        .should('not.exist')
                    cy.url().should('eq', 'targetUrl')
                    cy.visit('yourPageUrl')
                    cy.url().should('eq', 'yourPageUrl')
                    methodNumber ++
                    checkPaymentMethod(methodNumber)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Sure I'll try above use above approach as well.
Below code works for me. (Skipped clicking on secure checkout for now) Sure I'll try.
`var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      cy.get('img[class*="style__Logo"]').eq(i).invoke('attr', 'src').should('contain', 'https://static.XYZ.com')
    }`

Comment: If it works use that one but is good to know different approaches. Glad you found a way.

Comment: Sure. But thanks for your efforts.
I'll definitely try above code in couple of days.